# Unable to resolve "@react-native-community/masked-view

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using react native expo version 37.0.3 and every time I run the app I am getting this error`

```
Unable to resolve "@react-native-community/masked-view" from "node_modules\@react-navigation\stack\src\views\MaskedView.native.tsx"

Building JavaScript bundle: error`
```

I don't have any idea why this error is coming

[Here is the screenshot of error on my mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl2dq.png)

Comment: check this - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started#installing-dependencies-into-an-expo-managed-project

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You haven't followed the installation instructions for React Navigation.

Since you're using Expo, you should run

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

, as per the [getting started docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started).

Comment: I got the same issue ' Unable to resolve "@react-native-community/masked-view '. Thank you for your solution @Ben Butterworth. now it works.

Comment: My pleasure Mohamed Raza :)

Answer (score 1):

The @react-native-community/masked-view is a dependency you need to install to work with the the navigation stack.

Try doing:

```
expo install @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Answer (score 0):

For react native CLI users, try following

1. `npx react-native start --reset-cache`
2. Try deleting `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`/`yarn.lock` and reinstalling packages again

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes local cache and node modules will still cause errors while installing new library.
Then you can follow below commands in series in project folder:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clear --force
npm i
expo install @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Note : also force stop expo app could be better