# Unable to resolve module @react-native-masked-view/masked-view 2021

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

**I have already tried all of the answers in this previous thread and they have not worked**
[Unable to resolve "@react-native-community/masked-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61187578/unable-to-resolve-react-native-community-masked-view/61188350)

I have been unable to build my app in any capacity. Using expo ~42.0.0 to manage installations.

```
Unable to resolve module @react-native-masked-view/masked-view from 
/node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/src/MaskedViewNative.tsx
```

Here is that file on their main branch
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/elements/src/MaskedViewNative.tsx

Just curious what this error means, expo documentation says react navigation uses @react-native-community/masked-view this error and code in the latest release says other wise
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/masked-view/

Has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

> expo documentation says react navigation uses @react-native-community/masked-view

Expo documentation says React Navigation 5.x uses @react-native-community/masked-view. You're probably using React Navigation 6.x, not React Navigation 5.x. But it doesn't matter what Expo documentation says if you're getting an error because a specific package is missing and you already know which package it is.

You need to install `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view`:

```js
expo install @react-native-masked-view/masked-view
```